# Support toolbar not clickable on older apis

Tags: android, android-tabs, searchview, android-toolbar

I'm having difficulty getting the support toolbar to be clickable/touchable in API's less than 20.

And by that I mean, the `PageSlidingTabStrip` can't be swiped and the `searchView` can't be instantiated (details below ofc).

I don't understand, because I implemented from the beginning a support.`Toolbar`.
So here's the details of my implementation, which may render my toolbar not being clickable :

***layout.xml***

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    <com.insa.burnd.controller.PagerSlidingTabStrip ... />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

***onCreateOptionsMenu***

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(...);
    searchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.hint));
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    return true;
}
```

***menu_main***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="Filter"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

**Thank you :)**

Comment: shouldn't the slidingtabstrip be outside the toolbar?

Comment: No, because I'm having an effect where the slidingtabstrip in IN the toolbar, it's actually quite cool (like Tinder).